# Double infinite product $\prod_\limits{0<i<j<\infty} \left\{i^{\frac{1}{i}} - j^{\frac{1}{j}}\right\}$

Tags: finance, products, infinite-product

**Question**

Compute the products:

1. $\prod_\limits{0<i<j<\infty} \left\{i^{\frac{1}{i}} - j^{\frac{1}{j}}\right\}$
2. $\prod_\limits{0<i<j<2020} \left\{i^{\frac{1}{i}} - j^{\frac{1}{j}}\right\}$

From Isichenko (2021).

**Attempt at solution**

$\prod_\limits{0<i<j<\infty} \left\{i^{\frac{1}{i}} - j^{\frac{1}{j}}\right\} = \prod_\limits{i=0}^\infty \prod_\limits{j=i+1}^\infty \left\{i^{\frac{1}{i}} - j^{\frac{1}{j}}\right\}$

As $n$ tends towards infinity the $n$th root of n tends to 1.

$\lim_\limits{n \to \infty} \left\{\sqrt[n]{n}\right\} = \lim_\limits{n \to \infty} \left\{n^\frac{1}{n}\right\} = 1$

and

$i^\frac{1}{i} \gt j^\frac{1}{j} \; \forall \; j\gt i$

For every term in the product, since $j>i$ for every $i$

$\lim_\limits{i,j \to \infty} \left\{i^{\frac{1}{i}} - j^{\frac{1}{j}}\right\} = 0^+$

Therefore $\prod_\limits{0<i<j<\infty} \left\{i^{\frac{1}{i}} - j^{\frac{1}{j}}\right\} = 0$

For part 2. the same logic applies in that the term of the double product is always less than 1 and approaches 0.
$\prod_\limits{0<i<j<2020} \left\{i^{\frac{1}{i}} - j^{\frac{1}{j}}\right\} = 0$ or very small.

Is my solution correct, and if so, is there a more formal way of proving this result? Is there an exact answer to part 2.?

**Reference**

Isichenko, M. (2021) *Quantitative Portfolio Management: The Art and Science of Statistical Arbitrage.* Wiley.

Comment: $2^{1/2}=4^{1/4}.$

Comment: Even without the $0$ term, the terms go to zero and are bounded above by $1,$ so it seems like the product is going to be $0$ in the infinite case.