# Computing infinite product of differences

Tags: calculus, infinite-product

I'm reading Quantitative Portfolio Management by Isichenko, and one of the interview questions shared in the book is as follows:

> Compute the products:
>
> a. $\prod_{0 < i < j < \infty} (i^{1/i} - j^{1/j})$
>
> b. $\prod_{0 < i < j < 2020} (i^{1/i} - j^{1/j})$

I am confused by this question. On first glance, I'd imagine that if $i=2$ and $j=4$, then since $\sqrt{2} = \sqrt[4]{4}$ then the entire product becomes zero in both cases.. Am I missing the point here?

Comment: You passed. Interview questions esp. in the finance industry require often very little mathematical background. They just want to test your nerves.

Comment: Appears [already asked](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4581099). $\phantom{\text{WSAEWOULDCLOSE}}$.