# Calculate the product: $\prod\limits_{0<x<y<\infty} \left(x^{1/x} - y^{1/y}\right).$

Tags: infinite-product

Calculate the product: $$\prod_{0<x<y<\infty} \left(x^{1/x} - y^{1/y}\right).$$

Comment: There are infinitely many terms arbitrarily close to zero, and all of these terms are of absolute value $<1,$ so it must converge to zero.

Comment: Is there a way to see it using some explicit computations?

Comment: Performing explicit computations with this product is difficult because "$\prod_{0<x<y<\infty}$" needs to be properly  defined, although I imagine most reasonable definitions will result in a value of zero

Comment: What if the product is restricted to some number, let's say $\prod_{0<x<y<2023}$? I would expect the answer to still be close to zero. Maybe this helps in working with the product! I am more interested in finding a technique or strategy to address this kind of a problem.

Comment: [$2^{1/2}=4^{1/4}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4581099). Also asked [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4645203) :[|||||]:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well if you plot the graph $y=x^{1/x}$, you will notice that the graph reaches it's maxima at $x=e$ and $y=e^{1/e} \implies y\approx 1.4446$. So if you take any value of $y$ such that $y \gt 1 $, then $y^{1/y} \gt 1$. So $(x^{1/x} - y^{1/y}) \to 0$. Hence $$\prod_{0<x,y< \infty} (x^{1/x}-y^{1/y}) \to 0$$